# Moving a model between 3 points results in the model out of position

Tags: java, android, c++

I have a cube and I am moving it between 3 points (float positions) only on the x axis. So the cube will start at 0.00 I press the right key and it moves right on the x axis to 2.0f. I then press the left key and it moves back to 0.0f. I then press the left key again and it moves to -2.0f. Pressing the right key should now return it to 0.0f but instead it goes beyond 0. and the size of the error depends on the speed I move at.

This also has the same result if i start with the left key.

```
    if(MoveLeftFlag == true)
    {
        if(PositionFlag == 0)
        {
            if(Cube1.PositionX > MinCubeMovement)
            {
                Cube1.MoveLocalX(-CubeMoveSpeed * FrameTime );
            }
            else if(Cube1.PositionX < MinCubeMovement)
            {

                PositionFlag = -1;
                MoveLeftFlag = false;
            }
        }
        if(PositionFlag == 1)
        {
            if(Cube1.PositionX > Middle)
            {
                Cube1.MoveLocalX(-CubeMoveSpeed *  FrameTime );
            }
            else if(Cube1.PositionX < Middle)
            {
                MoveLeftFlag = false;
                PositionFlag = 0;
            }
        }
    }
    if(MoveRightFlag == true)
    {
        if(PositionFlag == 0)
        {
            if(Cube1.PositionX < MaxCubeMovement)
            {
                Cube1.MoveLocalX(CubeMoveSpeed *  FrameTime );
            }
            else if(Cube1.PositionX > MaxCubeMovement)
            {
                MoveRightFlag = false;
                PositionFlag = 1;
            }
        }
        if(PositionFlag == -1)
        {
            if(Cube1.PositionX < Middle)
            {
                Cube1.MoveLocalX(CubeMoveSpeed * FrameTime );
            }
            else if(Cube1.PositionX > Middle)
            {
                MoveRightFlag = false;
                PositionFlag = 0;
            }
        }
    }
```

FrameTime is `float frametime = getTimeInMillSeconds()/1000;`
and the speed is set to `0.000001f; which moves it at a nice smooth speed for me.
As i said if i make the speed greater then when the cube is returning to 0.0f for the second time the offset error becomes greater.

Can anyone point me in the right direction.

Comment: What does getTimeInMillSeconds() do? does it return time since it was last called or time since the start of the app?

Comment: It's called every frame to get the frametime then divided by 1000 to get frametime in seconds

Comment: sorry just to add - this is andriod opengl es 2.0 frametime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis()/1000; in the onDrawFrame

Comment: If you press right, wait a moment, then press left, the cube returns to its starting point? You're sure of that?

Comment: Yes it is only on the second return to the starting point that is has lost its position but reading up a bit more on SystemClock.upTimeMillis() 1. i dont think i am calculating Frametime correctly and two the documents state that this clock can be eracting at times. I will investigate further and post my answer

Comment: reading another article if i work FrameTime like this final long Time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
  
     final float FrameTime = mCurrentTime - Time;
     mCurrentTime = Time;   I still get the same problem

Comment: Using a fix FrameTime 1.0f/60.0f still didnt work so there must be something wrong with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok Well i have fixed the problem,surprised i didnt pick up on this but basically i was using < and > when i should have been using >= and <=.